# Loading MPS to PDF error

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, graphs

I am getting an error with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=5mm,
 right=5mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=20mm,
 }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\usegdlibrary{circular}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=4.5cm,
                    semithick, text=blue,state/.style={rectangle,rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,rectangle split part fill={red!30,white!20}, draw, minimum size=0.75cm}]
\graph [simple necklace layout]
    {

    \node[state]    Start,Hungup,Cancel Sms,Init1,Idle,SendSms1,TestModem,SendSms2,SendSms3;
  Start->Init1-> Idle;
Hungup ->Idle;
Idle->[bend left=10] Hungup;
 Hungup->TestModem;
Cancel Sms->[bend right=10]Idle;
 Idle->[bend right=5]Cancel Sms;
Idle->SendSms1;
SendSms1->[bend left=5]TestModem;
Cancel Sms->TestModem;
Init1->TestModem;
SendSms1->[bend left=5]SendSms2;
SendSms2->[bend right=5]SendSms3->Cancel Sms;
SendSms3->Idle;
TestModem->[loop]TestModem;

    };


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas where I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get errors, but LuaTeX enters an infinite loop. :(

Comment: @egreg any ideas how to solve it? :/

Comment: You should at least try and minimize your example

Comment: "an error" - which one?